# Vertical centering of text in texview not working

Tags: android

I'm sure this has been answered before but I've searched relentlessly and can't find an answer that fixes my exact problem, which is:

I have a TextView on top of an ImageView setup like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageForCustomAdapter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_ball_3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textOnBall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:hint="10"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageForCustomAdapter"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageForCustomAdapter"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageForCustomAdapter"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageForCustomAdapter"
    android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The TextView is aligned with the ImageView to make it the same size and I want the text to be centered both horizontally and vertically.

The render in Android Studio shows it to be centered correctly [This Pic Shows That](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106044397/Working%20in%20Android%20Studio.png)
But when I actually run the app on a real device the text only centers horizontally. I've tried all the different combinations of `android:gravity=` but nothing seams to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set image as background of TextView does not fit?

Comment: Use image as background of textview and remove imageview.

Comment: Use framelayout as kevin has suggested.  Or if you want to use shortcuts just add android:padding_left="10sp" but I wouldnt suggest this.

Comment: The image referenced in `android:src="@drawable/my_ball_3` is just a place holder so I can see what it looks like in the render. The actual images I am using are set at run time and are different depending on what occurs at run time. Can I set background at run time? I'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this with saying I really dislike RelativeLayout, and here's a great example.  Its powerful, but can be seriously confusing, and simplicity is important.

You've got *many* layout directives that can easily conflict with each other.  Try something like:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageForCustomAdapter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_ball_3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textOnBall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:hint="10"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The 'wrap_content' is important on the FrameLayout, btw.  Assuming the ImageView is always bigger than the TextView, it'll drive the parent height.  If the TextView might be bigger, make sure to center the ImageView as well.

Why it works in studio and not in real life, no idea.

Comment: Also, you could try the comments above, and use a background image.

Comment: That worked, mostly. The problem is that sometimes there are numbers with 2 digits, which look good, but when there is only one digit the text was pushed over to the left on the real device. But again, looked good in Studio... Weird. I'll try the background technique.